# Port 1433 blocked to Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, connection, linksys

I'm having an issue connecting to an Azure-hosted SQL Server. After much trial and error, and studying the handshake, I've determined that port 1433 is being blocked somewhere along the way. I've verified my local firewall is not blocking it, my ISP is not blocking it, and the internet in the building is not blocking it, leaving only the router to be the culprit. I can connect to the server if I'm wired into the wall, but not on the wifi.

I have a Linksys router, and disabling its firewall and attempting port forward have both failed to eliminate the problem. Has anyone else encountered this issue? Have any recommendations for going forward?

Comment: If you're able to connect from the wall, then it's not an Azure issue. I removed the [tag:azure] tag accordingly. Likely should remove [tag:sql-server] as well...

Comment: Yeah I have some recommendations going forward.  Use a wired connection. Don't use a linksys router.  This is a professional business environment, right?  Chalk it up to a faulty router and throw that stuff in the bin.